# Camunda Form failure: Value 'on' is not of type boolean

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am about to learn how to automate processes with Camunda and the Camunda Modeler.

Therefore, I set up a small test process with two user tasks, a decision table and a service task. Everything works fine, except one of the user tasks.

In the mentioned user task, I want to embed a little HTML-Form which looks like this:

```
<form role="form" name="form"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="download">Travel request to review</label>
        <a id="download" cam-variable-name="downloadRequest" cam-file-download="travelRequestDocument"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="checkboxApproved">I approve this travel request.</label>
      <input
      id="checkboxApproved"
      type="checkbox" 
      cam-variable-name="approved"
      cam-variable-type="boolean"
      class="form-control" />
     </div>
</form>
```

I embedded it through the form key property in the Camunda Modeler:

```
embedded:deployment:forms/approval.html
```

When I go to Camunda tasklist (Camunda engine runs on local tomcat server) and open the task, it says: `Form failure: Value 'on' is not of type boolean`.

I searched the internet back and forth for reasons which could cause this error, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Maybe someone here has experience with this kind of problem?

I would be very thankful :)

Comment: I found some kind of workaround for the problem: I changed the type of the input-HTML-element to 'text' . Now the error doesn't occur anymore, but there's also no checkbox shown in the form... Only a text input field. I am not really satisfied with this, so hopefully someone else has an idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: I just have to replace the "**b**oolean" with "**B**oolean" (uppercase 'b').
I hope this answer will save others from hours of research... (like me)